# Laravel not save the error files in storage folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

For example, if I get a laravel error in my view generates a file with string numbers:

```
ErrorException in 19d7345bcbbf651c1b34743d90b6a81a950dbcec.php line 3:
```

Previously these files are stored in the storage folder, but it is not currently saving.

how can I activate the saved again?

with a environment variable?

Comment: Do you want to save the errors in a log file or something to do with the views? It's not very clear.

Comment: Perhaps it is by the permission level

Answer (score 0):

Check For permission of storage folder.